# Error pinging docker server on "terraform apply"

Tags: docker, nginx, terraform

I am doing the terraform tutorial and reach the step to execute `terraform apply`.

After executing that command I get this error:

```
WARNING: cgroup v2 is not fully supported yet, proceeding with partial confinement

Error: Error pinging Docker server: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

  on main.tf line 9, in provider "docker":
   9: provider "docker" {
```

This is what I have in my configuration `main.tf`file:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source = "kreuzwerker/docker"
    }
  }
}

provider "docker" {
  
}

resource "docker_image" "nginx" {
  name         = "nginx:latest"
  keep_locally = false
}

resource "docker_container" "nginx" {
  image = docker_image.nginx.latest
  name  = "tutorial"
  ports {
    internal = 80
    external = 8000
  }
}
```

I have tried adding `host = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"` in the provider function but still get that error. I have docker and NGINX configured in my pc too.

Does anyone know what is causing it?

Comment: Is your user that is running Terraform either root or in the `docker` group?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR how can I check that?

Comment: You can run `groups` to see what groups your user is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run *docker run hello-world* with your user id you will see the same error that you are getting.
This is happening because your user doesn't have access to execute the commands of docker. Please do the following steps.

1. *`cat /etc/group`*  --> There should be a docker group available if you installed docker correctly.
2. Add your userid to docker group *`sudo usermod -aG docker $User_Name`*
3. Logout from the session and login again
4. *`docker run hello-world`*  --> This should run error free now.

Now try to apply Terraform again and everything will work.

Comment: This was not correct in my case. Terraform is looking for docker at the wrong sock path. unix:///var/run/docker.sock vs /run/containerd/containerd.sock

Comment: docker run hello-world works but still it gives me same error on windows
 Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 20, in resource "docker_container" "nginx":
│   20:   image = docker_image.nginx.latest
│
│ This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "latest".

Answer (score 9):

Ensure Docker CLI tools are installed under /usr/local/bin
and
Set /var/run/docker.sock which some third-party clients such as terrafor may use to communicate with Docker

[image]

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/permission-requirements/

Answer (score 6):

You can find your Docker Socket using the following command:

> docker context ls

And then update your provider block accordingly with the socket address

```
provider "docker" {
  host = "unix:///home/rehman/.docker/desktop/docker.sock"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `docker ps` command is successful then it means that the default host that provider of terraform uses is not correct.

Turning off Docker Desktop and writing docker ps shown me the path that it is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify the docker current endpoint with

```
docker context ls
```

and this is the result [image]

later paste `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` to

```
provider "docker" {
    host = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to reboot. In Linux. `systemctl restart docker` wasn't enough. Logging out and in again to Gnome wasn't enough. Just reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a machine in a corporate environment. If you can run `docker run hello-world` successfully, then your Docker installation is fine. Run `docker context ls` to print all contexts. The currently active context is indicated with an asterisk (*).

You can switch your context to back to default with `docker context use` for your tutorial:

`docker context use default`

Alternatively, you can change the provider block in your terraform main.tf file to another contact by specifying it:

```
provider "docker" {
  host = "your currently active context"
}
```

In my case, I suspect someone in IT added a corporately approved context without me knowing.

**Some background on contexts**

A [context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/) is a combination of several properties. These include:

- Name
- Endpoint configuration
- TLS info
- Orchestrator

The easiest way to see what contexts looks like is to view them:

`docker context ls`

When "default" is the active context, the asterisk in the `NAME` column indicates that this is the active context. This means all docker commands will be executed against the “default” context unless overridden with environment variables such as `DOCKER_HOST` and `DOCKER_CONTEXT`, or on the command-line with the `--context` and `--host` flags.