# `terraform init` Failed to install provider kreuzwerker/docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, terraform, hashicorp, ubuntu-21.04

**main.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    docker = {
      source  = "kreuzwerker/docker"
    }
    google = {
      source = "hashicorp/google"
    }
    random = {
      source = "hashicorp/random"
    }
  }
}

provider "docker" {}

resource "docker_image" "nginx" {
  name         = "nginx:latest"
  keep_locally = false
}

resource "docker_container" "nginx" {
  image = docker_image.nginx.latest
  name  = "tutorial"
  ports {
    internal = 80
    external = 8000
  }
}
```

Upon executing `terraform init` I face issue with downloading only docker resource:

```
Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/google...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/random...
- Finding latest version of kreuzwerker/docker...
- Installing hashicorp/google v4.11.0...
- Installed hashicorp/google v4.11.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/random v3.1.0...
- Installed hashicorp/random v3.1.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│ 
│ Error while installing kreuzwerker/docker v2.16.0: could not query provider registry for registry.terraform.io/kreuzwerker/docker: failed to retrieve authentication checksums for
│ provider: the request failed after 2 attempts, please try again later: Get
│ "https://github.com/kreuzwerker/terraform-provider-docker/releases/download/v2.16.0/terraform-provider-docker_2.16.0_SHA256SUMS": context deadline exceeded
```

After following [this post](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/error-failed-to-install-provider/16992) I downloaded the file in local and I get to perform terraform init successfully but failed to run terraform apply with below error:

```
│ Error: Could not load plugin
│ 
│ 
│ Plugin reinitialization required. Please run "terraform init".
│ 
│ Plugins are external binaries that Terraform uses to access and manipulate
│ resources. The configuration provided requires plugins which can't be located,
│ don't satisfy the version constraints, or are otherwise incompatible.
│ 
│ Terraform automatically discovers provider requirements from your
│ configuration, including providers used in child modules. To see the
│ requirements and constraints, run "terraform providers".
│ 
│ failed to instantiate provider "registry.terraform.io/kreuzwerker/docker" to obtain schema: fork/exec
│ .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/kreuzwerker/docker/2.16.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-docker_2.16.0_linux_amd64.zip: permission denied
```

System Details:

OS: Ubuntu 21.10

Terraform versions tried:

- 1.0.6 [same version used in tutorial cli at https://learn.hashicorp.com/]
- 1.1.16 [using apt-get]

I have also launched another docker container and reproduce the issue and I was able to reproduce the same issue with terraform init

---

---

### Update:

```
gahan@jarvis:~/devOps/test$ terraform init

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/random...
- Finding latest version of kreuzwerker/docker...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/google...
- Installing hashicorp/google v4.11.0...
- Installed hashicorp/google v4.11.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/random v3.1.0...
- Installed hashicorp/random v3.1.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│ 
│ Error while installing kreuzwerker/docker v2.16.0: could not query provider registry for registry.terraform.io/kreuzwerker/docker: failed to retrieve authentication checksums for provider: the request
│ failed after 2 attempts, please try again later: Get "https://github.com/kreuzwerker/terraform-provider-docker/releases/download/v2.16.0/terraform-provider-docker_2.16.0_SHA256SUMS": net/http: request
│ canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
╵

gahan@jarvis:~/devOps/test$ cat /etc/group | grep docker
docker:x:998:gahan

gahan@jarvis:~/devOps/test$ docker pull python:alpine3.13
alpine3.13: Pulling from library/python
5758d4e389a3: Pull complete 
9292b3ab1647: Pull complete 
35d95eb0acaf: Pull complete 
cfda6539f3f2: Pull complete 
f4471b8ea909: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:93eb0ba98b15791a071ec8bce2483e670e52c83af51962d3255b4f8f93b52d24
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:alpine3.13
docker.io/library/python:alpine3.13
```

Comment: What is the TF code that generates the error?

Comment: @Marcin updated to add the terraform code, I managed to get to basic getting started from tutorial same copy and yet it fails with the same error; on top of it I just added few more repo so that it can be clear that there is no network connection problem from my end which would block a certain provider and allow others

Comment: I run your code, and tf init works perfectly fine. So it must be something with either ubuntu or your setup.

Comment: I tried to pull latest docker container python:latest and within container also I faced the same issue and that too only with docker provider

Comment: To resolve it in my case I had to use VPN to bypass issue of ISP!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for help here @[Tapan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12105019/tapan-hegde) and other community members.

Since I followed all the steps of post installation steps, re-iterated permissions as well..

*In the end I also created a docker container to recreate issue and on further debugging it turns out that even though with `wget` command reported checksum can be downloaded, while working on terraform it might be using some other url/protocol which I am not yet aware of but it somehow conflicting with my ISP [Airtel fiber connection] .*

> As result I used [warp desktop client](https://pkg.cloudflareclient.com/packages/cloudflare-warp) and tried to use the
> terraform command which worked for me without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

@Gahan, I guess issue is with permissions, if i am not wrong, docker needs sudo access to run, where terraform works with normal user access. If you look at below line in error

```
.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/kreuzwerker/docker/2.16.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-docker_2.16.0_linux_amd64.zip: permission denied
```

It is showing "Permission denied".

I guess you can try changing user+group from sudo to your local user for .terraform directory and give a try.

```
chown <user>:<group> .terraform
chmod 750 .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/kreuzwerker/docker/2.16.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-docker_2.16.0_linux_amd64.zip
```

Update :

This setup is working fine with MacOS, I just tried to create ngnix container in docker using above main.tf contents and I am able to initialize and apply terraform successfully. I am using Mac OS. Terraform version - 1.1.1, Docker version - 4.4.2

Next, I tried to replicate same on ubuntu machine (20.04 LTS) and encountered similar issue as above when I tried to run "terraform apply"

Error:

```
 Error: Error pinging Docker server: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

On further digging I was able to resolve it.

The main cause of issue is our custom user doesn't have access to execute the commands of docker. So when terraform tries to run docker related commands, this fails. We can execute below steps to tackle this

1. There should be a docker group available if you installed docker correctly. This you can check in /etc/group path

```
$ cat /etc/group
```

2. Add your userid to docker group. In my case username is 'tapan1991'

```
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $User_Name

Eg : sudo usermod -aG docker tapan1991
```

3. Logout from the session and login again
4. Execute terraform plan/apply command

```
$ terraform apply
```

Hope this helps!!

Reference : [Error pinging docker server on "terraform apply"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67989620/error-pinging-docker-server-on-terraform-apply)

Comment: I have already configured docker post installation steps on system to not encounter the same. I can run any docker instance without going root.

Also, Permission denied is fallback of original root problem where terraform init fails to fetch provider zip itself.

Comment: @Gahan I just tried to create ngnix container in docker using above main.tf contents and I am able to initialize and apply terraform successfully. I am using Mac OS. Terraform version - 1.1.1, Docker version - 4.4.2

Comment: @Gahan On further update.. I tried to replicate same in ubuntu machine (20.04 LTS)..and encountered similar issue which you are facing " Error: Error pinging Docker server: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied"... on further digging I was able to resolve it..,.for more details check my updated answer.

Comment: group exist in /etc/group as `docker:x:998:gahan` but yet getting failure, further debugging turns out that even after all those post installation step there's still some issue with few docker pull repos, i.e. was able to pull hello-world and python:latest but failed to pull ubuntu:20.04

Comment: I added more detailed steps of debug if that helps...

Comment: @Gahan, This might sound stupid question, Just wanted to check are you running above terraform commands while connected to VPN or any private network? When you try to access this URL "https://github.com/kreuzwerker/terraform-provider-docker/releases/download/v2.16.0/terraform-provider-docker_2.16.0_SHA256SUMS".. were you able to download checksum file locally? or it failed?

Comment: Hey, this is really weird but I am able to download checksum file url with `wget` successfully, and no I am not using any proxy connection!!

Comment: It's really weird that I tried on one of the other remote system apart from my existing ISP and it worked as expected. Seems like this is issue from ISP - Airtel Fiber connection; I simply used latest version of warp VPN and it worked for me!